# get session attribute in php

Tags: php, session, attributes

Hello I have developed a small menu bar in jsp which collects attribute of a session and displays menu according to it.

```
<li><%
        String myname =  (String)session.getAttribute("name");           
        if(myname!=null && !myname.equals("admin"))                {

             %>
             <a href="logout.jsp" ><span>Logout</span></a></li>
             <li><span>Welcome <%=myname%></span></li>
             <%
            }
        else if(myname!=null && myname.equals("admin"))
            {

             %>
             <a href="logout.jsp" ><span>Logout</span></a></li>
             <li><span>Welcome Admin</span></li>
```

I want this same code in php .I tried it but in vain as I am newbie to php.So my question is how to get session attribute as name and password, in php ?

Comment: you may access the session using the super global array `$_SESSION`

Comment: Note that the way how the JSP is written there is considered "legacy" and is strongly discouraged since introduction of JSP 2.0 almost a decade ago in favor of taglibs/EL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to access the session using $_SESSION superglobal. You may call session_start(); before that to start the session if not already started.

```
<?php $myname =  $_SESSION['name'];           
if (!empty($myname) && $myname != 'admin'): ?>
    <a href="logout.jsp" ><span>Logout</span></a></li>
    <li><span>Welcome <?php echo $myname; ?></span></li>
<?php else if (!empty($myname) && $myname == 'admin'): ?>
    <a href="logout.jsp" ><span>Logout</span></a></li>
    <li><span>Welcome Admin</span></li>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Beware of typo: SESSOIN. Should of course be: SESSION

Answer (score 1):

```
you can use $_SESSION['name'] to retrieve session values in php

<?php
session_start();
$name =  $_SESSION['name'];
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the session in PHP you need to start them first

For example

```
session_start();
```

To store a session variable you need to make a new $_SESSION variable. Example:

```
$_SESSION['username'] = 'Demo';
$_SESSION['password'] = "demo123";
```

And to get the stored sessions use:

```
echo $_SESSION['username'];
```

This is all very basic PHP. I recommend you to look up some tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP Session is used as follows,

```
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['name'];
echo $_SESSION['password'];
```

Try print_r to get all session values as,

```
print_r($_SESSION);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code converted to PHP:

```
<li>
<?php
$myname = $_SESSION["name"];
if($myname != null && $myname != "admin") {
?>
<a href="logout.php" ><span>Logout</span></a></li>
<li><span>Welcome <?php echo $myname; ?></span></li>
<?php
} elseif($myname != null && $myname == "admin") {
?>
<a href="logout.php" ><span>Logout</span></a></li>
<li><span>Welcome Admin</span></li>
```